# Delta Live Table - Cannot redefine dataset

Tags: databricks, live, delta

I am new to Delta Live Table.

I am trying to create a delta live table from the databricks tutorial.

I have created a notebook and attached an interactive cluster -DBR 14.3-LTS.

I am running the below code.

When I ran it for the 1st time it ran successfully.

When I ran the cell for the 2nd time I am getting error - AnalysisException: Cannot redefine dataset 'sales_orders_raw'

Can you please help me understand why this is happening?

---

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import dlt

@Dlt.create_table(
  comment="The raw sales orders, ingested from /databricks-datasets.",
  table_properties={
    "myCompanyPipeline.quality": "bronze",
    "pipelines.autoOptimize.managed": "true"
  }
)
def sales_orders_raw():
  return (
    spark.readStream.format("cloudFiles") \
      .option("cloudFiles.schemaLocation", "/tmp/john.odwyer/pythonsalestest") \
      .option("cloudFiles.format", "json") \
      .option("cloudFiles.inferColumnTypes", "true") \
      .load("/databricks-datasets/retail-org/sales_orders/")
  )
```

---

Can you please help me understand what I am doing wrong

Comment: Try changing Dlt.create_table  to dlt.table instead.

Comment: I tried that. But no luck

Comment: I tried this and your code works fine no matter how many times I run it with full refresh or updates. Maybe uou need to share some more info on how you created the pipelines settings. We need to recreate the problem to solve it.

Comment: I have not created pipeline yet. I am developing the notebook. There when I run the cell twice, I am getting issue